# Applescript Webforms

Tags: ajax, applescript

I am trying to make an applescript that submit a form on mxtoolbox.com that uses AJAX at this link:

http://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell (make new document) to set URL to "http://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx"
    delay 10
    tell application "System Events"
-- Copies text from variable headerText to clipboard and paste. Faster than keystroke headerText
        set the clipboard to headerText
        keystroke "v" using command down

    end tell
end tell
```

Any ideas?

A suggestion was the following but it still did not work:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell (make new document) to set URL to "http://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx"
    delay 10
    tell application "System Events"
        set the clipboard to headerText
        keystroke "v" using command down
        tell application "Safari"
            do JavaScript ("
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToolInput').value='" & headerText as text) & "';
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAction').click();
" in document 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with JavaScript:

```
set headerText to "test"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell (make new document) to set URL to "http://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx"
    delay 5

    do JavaScript "
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToolInput').value=" & quoted form of headerText & ";
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAction').click()" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: I changed the answer to the full script. In my test it pastes "test" and clicks the "Analyze Header" button.

Comment: The problem is with the quotes in the header. I will run it through a parser and let you know how that works on Monday! @user309603

Comment: Ok It did answer my question but this answer will not allow for passing of header unless it is parsed of all line breaks.